# require.js uncaught typeerror: cannot read property '__module_path__; of undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

So I've just started to try to get to grips with require.js and it doesn't seem to be working.
When I include it in my html using the tag:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="bower_components/require/build/require.js"></script>
```

I get the following error upon loading the page in chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__MODULE_PATH__' of undefined  -> require.js:538
```

In firefox I get a slightly different error:

```
TypeError: parent is undefined -> require.js:538
```

No idea how I could be causing this problem as It's a fresh install of require.js and I have no code in my main.js yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure that in dependecies list you put `requirejs`, not `require`, since that is slightly different project, (created just few days ago): http://bower.io/search/?q=require